# Reformatting the Choice Field to be more user friendly

Tags: sharepoint-designer, custom-form, choice-field, edit-form

This is an odd one, so I appreciate any help with this.  We have a choice field, Work Status, on a list used for project tracking.  Over the course of requirements creep (out of my control!), the field now has... a lot of statuses in it.  So, I'm looking at making the choice field a little more user friendly and natural to use.  Basically, I want to go from this:

[image: Current State]

To something like this (pardon my hasty image editing):

[image: Desired State]

Wherein the arrows scroll smoothly through the available choices.

I'm a little tool-limited by our enterprise.  I can use SP Designer and I personally know enough JS/jQuery, CSS, and HTML to get by.  I won't be able to access the server itself or stsadm.  For no apparent reason, I also can't enable InfoPath Forms Services, so that's out.

Thanks, in advance, for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use SharePoint designer to edit the editform.aspx and newform.aspx for your list and add some javascript/jquery to the page to accomplish what you want.  I've done this before to hide columns or change the behavior with good results.

Comment: Right on.  I'll see what I can do.  Thanks for the suggestion.  Any ideas on a starting place?

Comment: I just did a quick ask of the google and it came back with this:  http://www.sharepointboris.net/2007/07/refferencing-sharepoint-form-fields-with-javascript/

Comment: Awesome!  Thank you!  (Our network is super locked down, so I never would have found this).